# Unsigned MD5_Number_Lower64 hash outcome

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, md5

I'm working on generating the unique ID for a table using hashing. The requirement is:-

1. ID should be unsigned.
2. ID should be numeric.

MD5_NUMBER_LOWER64 - https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/md5_number_lower64.html

Will, there be any scenario where the number returned by it might get duplicated? If yes,
what is the probability they get duplicated after how many records?

For ex -
Consider I've two numbers 228 and 128, will there be a chance that the outcome from both the numbers is the same?

I'm thinking in the sense that it will return Endian 64 bit and it could be similar.

Comment: Every hash has collisions.  It is inevitable when you are mapping something larger into something smaller.  However, unless someone is intentionally trying to do so, the chances of a random MD5 collision are infinitesimal.

Comment: Risk of collision depends on how many values you're hashing. If many (billions) values then collisions will become likely - see last part of https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/hash.html#usage-notes